# Scraper fails to print all results

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've written a script in python to scrape "name" and "phone" of five items from craigslist. The problem I'm facing is that when I run my script, It only gives three results instead of five results. To be more specific, as the first two links do not have additional link (contact info) in their page so they do not need to make another request for opening any additional page. However the two links that do not have (contact info) links can't infiltrate through the "if ano_page_link:" statement in my second function and never get printed. How can I fix this flaw so that whether it has got phone number or not the scraper will print all the five results.

The script I'm trying with:

```
import re ; import requests ; from lxml import html

base = "http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in"

url_list = [
'http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/flat-is-for-sale-at-cooke-town/6266183606.html',
'http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/prestige-sunnyside/6259128505.html',
'http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/jayanagar-2nd-block-4000-sft/6221720477.html',
'http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/prestige-ozone-type-3-r-villa/6259928614.html',
'http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/zed-homes-3-bedroom-flat-for/6257075793.html'
]

def get_link(medium_link):
    response = requests.get(medium_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    try:
        name = tree.cssselect('span#titletextonly')[0].text
    except IndexError:
        name = ""
    try:
        link = base + tree.cssselect('a.showcontact')[0].attrib['href']
    except IndexError:
        link = ""
    parse_doc(name, link)

def parse_doc(title, ano_page_link):

    if ano_page_link:
        page = requests.get(ano_page_link).text            
        tel = re.findall(r'\d{10}', page)[0] if re.findall(r'\d{10}', page) else ""
        print(title, tel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in url_list:
        get_link(link)
```

Results I'm having:

```
Jayanagar 2nd Block, 4000 sft Plot for Sale 9845012673
PRESTIGE OZONE TYPE D 3 B/R VILLA FOR SALE 9611226364
T ZED HOMES 3 BEDROOM FLAT FOR SALE 9611226364
```

Results I'm expecting:

```
A Flat is for sale at  Cooke Town
Prestige Sunnyside
Jayanagar 2nd Block, 4000 sft Plot for Sale 9845012673
PRESTIGE OZONE TYPE D 3 B/R VILLA FOR SALE 9611226364
T ZED HOMES 3 BEDROOM FLAT FOR SALE 9611226364
```

Comment: Do you make function definition inside `for` loop? Why?

Comment: Sorry sir. I should not have. I did that for this demo.

Comment: Modified as you suggested sir Andersson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, for example, on http://bangalore.craigslist.co.in/reb/d/flat-is-for-sale-at-cooke-town/6266183606.html there is no link matched by `'a.showcontact'` selector, so following block

```
try:
    link = base + tree.cssselect('a.showcontact')[0].attrib['href']
except IndexError:
    link = ""
```

will return `link = ""`

Then when you call `if ano_page_link:` all commands in `if` block are ignored as condition `if ""` is `False` and nothing is printed out

You can try below instead:

```
def parse_doc(title, ano_page_link):

    if ano_page_link:
        page = requests.get(ano_page_link).text            
        tel = re.findall(r'\d{10}', page)[0] if re.findall(r'\d{10}', page) else ""
        print(title, tel)
    else:
        print(title)
```

Comment: Thanks sir  Andersson, for your answer. It fixed the problem. I also thought about "else' block but my ignorance did not let me do that. Lol!!. You are a life saver. Thanks sir once again.

Comment: One additional thing to know sir. In normal cases when it comes to write data in csv, I would place the line just after or around print statement "writer.writerow([title,tel])". However, could you suggest me how should i modify this line as  "title" appears here twice (in the print statement). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure as I have a little expirience with `.csv`, but you can try something like `if ano_page_link:...writer.writerow([title,tel])`, `else: writer.writerow([title," "])`

Comment: Your solution is never meant to go wrong. It did the trick. Thanks again sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain more flexibility by separating the two tasks **collect data** and **print data**. It will be easier to add more infos later when you want to extend.

```
def collect_info(medium_link):
    response = requests.get(medium_link).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)

    title = get_title(tree)
    contact_link = get_contact_link(tree)
    tel = get_tel(contact_link) if contact_link else ''

    return title, tel


def get_title(tree):
    try:
        name = tree.cssselect('span#titletextonly')[0].text
    except IndexError:
        name = ""
    return name

def get_contact_link(tree):
    try:
        link = base + tree.cssselect('a.showcontact')[0].attrib['href']
    except IndexError:
        link = ""
    return link

def get_tel(ano_page_link):
    page = requests.get(ano_page_link).text
    tel = re.findall(r'\d{10}', page)[0] if re.findall(r'\d{10}', page) else ""
    return tel

def print_info(title, tel):
    if tel:
        fmt = 'Title: {title}, Phone: {tel}'
    else:
        fmt = 'Title: {title}'
    print(fmt.format(title=title, tel=tel))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in url_list:
        title, tel = collect_info(link)
        print_info(title, tel)
```